# Проблема с установкой node-sass под windows 8.1

Tags: windows, docker, webpack, scss, docker-compose

OS windows 8.1
Имеется контейнер docker с node js (среди других прочих контейнеров)

```
  manager-node:
    image: node:12.13-alpine
    volumes:
      - //D_DRIVE/work/5_project-manager/manager:/app
    working_dir: /app
```

Также имеется symfony 4.3 с установленным encore. 
Вот файл package.json

```
{
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.28.0",
        "core-js": "^3.1.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.8.0"
    }
}
```

В терминале phpstorm запускаю команду установки: (без флага --no-bin-links получаю ошибки и папка .bin не создаётся)

```
docker-compose run --rm manager-node npm install --no-bin-links
```

После чего пакеты устанавливаются и после установки я запускаю команду `docker-compose run --rm manager-node npm run dev`

которая отрабатывает с ошибкой:

```
D:\work\5_project-manager>docker-compose run --rm manager-node npm run dev

> @ dev /app
> encore dev

sh: encore: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @ dev: `encore dev`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-18T18_39_46_656Z-debug.log
```

Вспомнив, что недавно я запускал команду npm install напрямую из windows иду в ту папку node_modules и копирую оттуда папку .bin , после чего команда `docker-compose run --rm manager-node npm run dev` начинает работать вроде бы нормально.
Вопрос: как через команду `docker-compose run --rm manager-node npm install` установить пакеты корректно, чтобы они работали после установки? Ведь копировать вручную папку .bin - это крайне неправильно!!!